# html fetch multiple files

Tags: html, standards, fetch-api

I would like to fetch multiple files at once using the new fetch api (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/). Is is possible natively? If so, how should I do it leveraging the promises?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var list = [];
var urls = ['1.html', '2.html', '3.html'];
var results = [];

urls.forEach(function(url, i) { // (1)
  list.push( // (2)
    fetch(url).then(function(res){
      results[i] = res.blob(); // (3)
    })
  );
});

Promise
  .all(list) // (4)
  .then(function() {
    alert('all requests finished!'); // (5)
  });
```

**This is untested code!** Additionally, it relies on `Array.prototype.forEach` and the new `Promise` object of ES6. The idea works like this:

1. Loop through all URLs.
2. For each URL, fetch it with the `fetch` API, store the returned promise in `list`.
3. Additionally, when the request is finished, store the result in `results`.
4. Create a new promise, that resolves, when all promises in `list` are resolved (i.e., all requests finished).
5. Enjoy the fully populated `results`!

Comment: great! I'll test it now and let you know if anything goes wrong!! Thanks

Comment: Cool! (After all, it was the first time, that I used all that stuff in combination. Good to see, that my JS intuition still holds in ES6 land...)

Answer (score 2):

While implementing [Boldewyn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29676966/3939277) in Kotlin, I pared it down to this:

```kotlin
fun fetchAll(vararg resources: String): Promise<Array<out Response>> {
    return Promise.all(resources.map { fetch(it) }.toTypedArray())
}
```

Which roughly translates to this in JavaScript:

```javascript
function fetchAll(...resources) {
    var destination = []
    resources.forEach(it => {
        destination.push(fetch(it))
    })
    return Promise.all(destination)
}
```

<sub>Earlier, I tried to use `map` instead of `forEach` + `push`ing to a new array, but for some reason that simply didn't work.</sub>